# sample speed i2c

Tags: debian, python, c, i2c

If running standard release of debian on my Rpi. How fast can I sample the sensor readings through i2c and save values?

Why Im asking, I tried to read a DS18B20 and save it,s values (wrote the program in python) running xwin and it seems to be very slow.

Right now Im just samplig every 5th second. If I want to measure power readings (AC), they should be done much faster.

Will a C compiled code run much faster?

Kind Regards

Comment: DS18B20 is a 1-wire interface, not i2c

Comment: You could post your python code so we can see what exactly it is doing. It probably waits for sensor to be ready since it takes some time for DS18B20 before you can read temperature value.

Comment: The question is about i2c! My experience is with a DS18B20 with a bit banging process in the kernel (Occidentalis release). Yes, I made my python program not to accept the new value if the CRC check wherent ok. So that loop could take some extra time.

Comment: Here is speed a comparison of C and Python: [link](http://theunixgeek.blogspot.com/2008/09/c-vs-python-speed.html)

Comment: But you want to measure the voltage on a high enough frequency to create a nice sinus? Or you (also) want to  measure the current to calculate some dissipation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DS18B20 is OneWire Interface which was mentioned before. As documentation states with maximal accuruacy You can sample not faster than every 750ms + if you use multiple devices on one "bus" You have to count additional time to query device with specified serial number.

Of course You can use i2c to poke 1w devices, but it's a waste as it is not much more complicated by simply toggling standard gpio or easiest way - using kernel module.